# Vertical alignment with floatrow

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, floatrow

I am playing with `floatrow`, however the images are not aligned at the top and I do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{floatrow}
\floatbox{figure}[0.4\textwidth][\FBheight][t]
{\caption{first image positioned at the top}
 \label{fig:floatrow:example:3:a}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{images/TestBild.png}}
%
\floatbox{figure}[0.4\textwidth][\FBheight][t]
{\caption{second image positioned at the top}
 \label{fig:floatrow:example:3:b}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/TestBild.png}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
```

also I would like to add a defined spacing between the pictures, but have not found out how. Typically I add either `\hspace{2em}` or `\hfill`, but both do nothing if inserted between the commands (as expected).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the option `heightadjust=object` for `\floatsetup`, as I did in the following example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\floatsetup{heightadjust=object}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\floatbox{figure}[.4\textwidth][\FBheight][t]
{\caption{first image positioned at the top}
 \label{fig:floatrow:example:3:a}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth,height=7cm]{images/TestBild.png}}\hspace*{1cm}
%
\floatbox{figure}[.4\textwidth][\FBheight][t]
{\caption{second image positioned at the top}
 \label{fig:floatrow:example:3:b}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/TestBild.png}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I used the `demo` option for the `graphicx` package to replace the images with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual code.

[image]

Comment: why do you need `valign=t`if this is already included in the floatbox command?

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: you're right; `valign=t` is not necessary with your code.